# Navigation breadcrumb : using css and html

Tags: css, html

Please check this image link :
http://postimg.org/image/4iooctxxt/

As you can see, I pointed out the 3 navigation breadcrumb.

How I am able to obtain this with CSS/CSS3 and HTML. How can this be done? If it's possible, how can it be done with a background image.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: short answer, Possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this HTML and CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body
        {
            margin: auto;
        }

        #one, #two, #three
        {
            position: relative;
            width: 200px;
            height: 40px;
            float: left;
            background-color: #E6E6E6;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-top: 1px solid gray;
            border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
        }

        #one
        {
            border-left: 1px solid gray;
        }

        #one:after, #two:after, #three:after
        {
            position: absolute;
            width: 0; 
            height: 0; 
            border-top: 20px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
            border-left: 10px solid #E6E6E6;
            left: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            content: "";
            z-index: 1;
        }

        #one:hover, #two:hover, #three:hover
        {
            background-color: #4DB84D;
        }

        #one:hover:after, #two:hover:after, #three:hover:after
        {
            border-left: 10px solid #4DB84D;
        }

        #circle, #text
        {
            float: left;
        }

        #circle
        {
            position: relative;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 21px;
            height: 21px;
            left: 15px;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -12px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }

        #text
        {
            position: relative;
            left: 20px;
            top: 50%;
            color: black;
            margin-top: -11px;
        }

        #one:hover #circle, #two:hover #circle, #three:hover #circle
        {
            background-color: #009900;
            color: white;
        }

        #one:hover #text, #two:hover #text, #three:hover #text
        {
            color: black;
        }

        #navigation
        {
            padding: 40px;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: black;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        <div id="one">
            <div id="circle">
                <b>1</b>
            </div>
            <div id="text">
                Connect with Facebook
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <div id="circle">
                <b>2</b>
            </div>
            <div id="text">
                Invite friends
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="three">
            <div id="circle">
                <b>3</b>
            </div>
            <div id="text">
                Complete Profile
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

You can copy and paste this to see what happens in a new html document.
You can, of course, modify it to your needs.

EDIT: This is now a full template. To see, create a new html document, copy and paste the code, and open it.

Comment: Oh Nice. I think it will help me for sure thanks @Frederik Moller

Comment: I made it look more like the link you specified (edited my code).

Comment: PLease change Ids like `navigation` and `circle` to classes. Id's should be unique on a page

Answer (score 0):

include bootstrap file to your code. example:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="active">Data</li>
</ol>
```

it will create breadcrumb

Comment: Nice Suggestion, however OP wants to do it in CSS/CSS3

Comment: Yes , this breadcrum i am able to do, but using css i am not able achieve the  UI like that i have shown in the picture.